# Getting user defined constants into the preamble

Tags: macros, hyperref, expansion, preamble, import

I think this is a problem of expandable content, a concept I haven't quite got the hang of yet...

Lets say I have a preamble or cls file that is trying to configure `hyperref`.
If I have manually setup a command for the author using `\newcommand{\Me}{EngBIRD}` I can then use it when configuring the document properties like so:

```
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={\Me},                % author
    pdfcreator={\Me},               % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={\Me}               % producer of the document
}
```

**Problem**:  In the template I am creating, the tex file is just a template.  It links to content in tex files (such as the demo file `LaTeX_Personal_Details.autotex`) which have have been automatically created local to the project.

```
\long\def\PersonalFirstName{I.}
\long\def\PersonalMiddleName{Eng}
\long\def\PersonalLastName{BIRD}
\long\def\PersonalPhoneNumber{Phone Number here}
\long\def\PersonalAddressLineOne{Street Address Here}
\long\def\PersonalAddressLineTwo{City, Province, Country Address Here}
\long\def\PersonalEmail{Email Here}
```

This content is then included and used using custom designed commands that the MWE will illustrate.

I have tried a bunch of command definitions (see the commented out lines below `xparse`) but I am sure they aren't working because the hypersetup is populated with an unexpanded macro that hasn't even imported it's data yet...  I thought the multiple compile iterations would work around the order problem, so I am left thinking that this is an expandable content problem...

Is there a way I can allow the user information stored in the pdf properties to be driven by the same data that populates the document?  Was I maybe on the right track with `DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` but just stuck with it's requirement that the last argument not be optional (this I don't understand either when default values can be passed and are not empty)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

    %\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\Me}{ O{\PersonalFirstName} O{\PersonalMiddleName} O{\PersonalLastName} }{#1~#2~#3} % has potential, but doesn't compile with only optional arguments
    %\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Me}{ O{\PersonalFirstName} O{\PersonalMiddleName} O{\PersonalLastName} }{#1~#2~#3}
    %\def\Me#1{\gdef\@Me{#1}}
    %\Me{\PersonalFirstName~\PersonalMiddleName~\PersonalLastName}

    %\newcommand{\Me}{\PersonalFirstName~\PersonalMiddleName~\PersonalLastName}

    \newcommand{\Me}{EngBIRD}

    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\CustomTitleBlock}{ O{\PersonalFirstName} O{\PersonalMiddleName} O{\PersonalLastName} }
    {%
        {#1~#2~#3}
    }%

    \makeatletter   
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\PersonalDataBlock}{ }
    {%
        {E-mail:}\PersonalEmail 

        {Phone:}\PersonalPhoneNumber

        {Address:}\PersonalAddressLineOne{,}\PersonalAddressLineTwo
    }%
    \makeatother    

%=========================================================================================================================================
% PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR HYPERLINKS AND HYPER-REFERENCES
%=========================================================================================================================================

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

    \hypersetup{
        breaklinks=true,
        hypertexnames=false,
        %bookmarks=false,               % show bookmarks bar?
        unicode=true,                   % non-Latin characters in Acrobat's bookmarks
        pdftoolbar=true,                % show Acrobat's toolbar?
        pdfmenubar=true,                % show Acrobat's menu?
        pdffitwindow=true,              % window fit to page when opened
        pdfstartview={FitV},            % fits the height of the page to the window:  or fits the width of the page to the window  FitH
        pdftitle={CV - \Me},            % title
        pdfauthor={\Me},                % author
        %pdfsubject={Subject},          % subject of the document
        pdfcreator={\Me},               % creator of the document
        pdfproducer={\Me},              % producer of the document
        %pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
        pdfnewwindow=true,              % links in new window
        colorlinks=true,                % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,                % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
        citecolor=black,                % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=black,                % color of file links
        urlcolor=black                  % color of external links
    }

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

%--------------------Load Data for Title and Contact information-------------
\input{LaTeX_Personal_Details.autotex}

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\CustomTitleBlock

%--------------------CONTACT INFORMATION-----------------------------------
\PersonalDataBlock

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\providecommand{\PersonalFirstName}{}` etc. to make them at least defined when `\Me` comes into action. I think that a key-value interface might be better here, using a command with an mandatory argument.

Comment: at the very least you'd need to input `LaTeX_Personal_Details.autotex` earlier before you use the commands it defines.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Will try that now.  Are you suggesting replacing the `\long\def\PersonalFirstName` with `providecommand` or are you still using both?  Sorry this feels like a dumb question.

Comment: \Me is using commands from `LaTeX_Personal_Details.autotex`. hypersetup is using \Me. This means the commands must be known when hypersetup is executed. You must input the file earlier as David already wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to generate

```
Title:          CV - I. Eng BIRD
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         I. Eng BIRD
Creator:        I. Eng BIRD
Producer:       I. Eng BIRD
CreationDate:   Thu Mar 31 16:27:05 2016
ModDate:        Thu Mar 31 16:27:05 2016
```

Which I got from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\input{LaTeX_Personal_Details.autotex}

\newcommand{\Me}{\PersonalFirstName\space\PersonalMiddleName\space\PersonalLastName}

    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\CustomTitleBlock}{ O{\PersonalFirstName} O{\PersonalMiddleName} O{\PersonalLastName} }
    {%
        {#1~#2~#3}
    }%

    \makeatletter   
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\PersonalDataBlock}{ }
    {%
        {E-mail:}\PersonalEmail 

        {Phone:}\PersonalPhoneNumber

        {Address:}\PersonalAddressLineOne{,}\PersonalAddressLineTwo
    }%
    \makeatother    

%=========================================================================================================================================
% PACKAGES REQUIRED FOR HYPERLINKS AND HYPER-REFERENCES
%=========================================================================================================================================

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

    \hypersetup{
        breaklinks=true,
        hypertexnames=false,
        %bookmarks=false,               % show bookmarks bar?
        unicode=true,                   % non-Latin characters in Acrobat's bookmarks
        pdftoolbar=true,                % show Acrobat's toolbar?
        pdfmenubar=true,                % show Acrobat's menu?
        pdffitwindow=true,              % window fit to page when opened
        pdfstartview={FitV},            % fits the height of the page to the window:  or fits the width of the page to the window  FitH
        pdftitle={CV - \Me},            % title
        pdfauthor={\Me},                % author
        %pdfsubject={Subject},          % subject of the document
        pdfcreator={\Me},               % creator of the document
        pdfproducer={\Me},              % producer of the document
        %pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
        pdfnewwindow=true,              % links in new window
        colorlinks=true,                % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=black,                % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
        citecolor=black,                % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=black,                % color of file links
        urlcolor=black                  % color of external links
    }

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

%--------------------Load Data for Title and Contact information-------------


%--------------------TITLE-------------
\CustomTitleBlock

%--------------------CONTACT INFORMATION-----------------------------------
\PersonalDataBlock

\end{document}
```